# Conditional check inside Image element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new with *react-native* and I know that it's possible to add an image in different ways.

For local images:

```
<Image source={require('/react-native/img/favicon.png')} />
```

And for remote images:

```
<Image
    style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
    source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png'}}
/>
```

I want to check if a link is provided. If yes, I want to display the image and if not, I want to display a local one. My code looks like this:

```
var image = null
if (item && itame.image){
    image = item.image
}

const defaultImage = '/react-native/img/favicon.png'

return (
    <Image source={{ uri: image}} />
);
```

How can I in `source` check if the image is `null` or not and display the appropriate image?

Comment: You can try `source={{ uri: (image === null) ? defaultImage : image}}`. Or otherwise, call a method that will do the check and return the image you want to show.

Comment: For local images, 'uri:' ist not used so this will not work

Comment: Then try `source={(image === null) ? defaultImage : { uri: image }}`

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted the answer in the comments, so I will move it here for anyone else who is interested:

`<Image source={(image === null) ? defaultImage : { uri: image }} />`